# I want to know if this is correct

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I just want to clarify whether this code seems right for the query I am trying to run as a statement . The query is to **Write a SQL statement to list the cinema numbers of cinemas which employ more than four employees.**  Does it seem correct ? I've run the statement and have had multiple different clauses included and ended up using having instead of Where for the "> 4 ".

This is the code I have created below

```
    SELECT Cinema_No AS Cinema , COUNT (Emp_no) AS Employee_Count
    FROM Employee
    GROUP BY CINEMA_NO 
    HAVING COUNT(EMP_NO) > 4
    ORDER BY CINEMA_NO ASC ;
```

Comment: The query should answer the question.

Comment: You can test your queries online, for free - you don't even need to install a SQL system on your computer (although of course you could). Need help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "YES"

- You are listing the cinema numbers, and their counts
- You are properly filtering using the `HAVING` clause which allows you to filter on aggregate function

Comment: Cheers , just needed some confirmation since I'm new to SQL . Thanks for explaining why it would work . Very informative :)

Comment: No problem. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

Query looks good, count(emp_no) will ignore if the emp_no value is null.
[image]